# Sign in with Apple. Get user phone number

Tags: ios, swift, apple-sign-in

In my application users can log in or register with phone number, verified via SMS-code.  A phone number is a non-optional field, like a primary key. Some day I added log in with social network which provides user's phone number. Now Apple asks me to add *Sign in with Apple*. But I can not find how to retrieve user's phone after getting `ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential`. It it possible? Or I have to ask Apple not to add *Sign in with Apple* button?

Comment: You can't get it automatically and and unless you fit a very specific criteria such as an education institution you can't avoid Sign In With Apple if you use 3rd parties for login. You can always create a screen that pops up to have the user put in the phone number but you should have a really good reason for having it.

Answer (score 2):

Personal data should not be used as primary keys for an authentication system. The user should be able to change his email, phone number, name, address... without breaking your whole database. You should definitely assign to your users a random UUID at registration time, and then use it as a primary key.

You are right about the fact you have to add SignIn With Apple if you implement any 3rd party social login, but those will not always provide you a phone number (it is not mandatory for Facebook, Google, Linkedin...). Apple goes further and may also hide the real email address by providing an alias. For data privacy concerns, Apple will reject an application that requires the user to provide its email and phone number without a strong business justification. If you think you are legitimate to require it, you can implement a profile completion right after the login, that will check if all the required data are already known, and prevent the user from going further into the application before he fills the missing data.

However in this case, you should explain to the user (to avoid drop off) and to the Apple reviewer (to avoid rejection) why those data are mandatory to use your app.